# Partial default specialization of multiple parameter template

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

Is there a way to extract a partial default specialization from the compiler?

Say that I have this two parameter template:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct X {
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

and I also have some code that makes use of a single parameter template, like this:

```
template<template<typename> class T, typename B>
struct make_T_of_B {
    T<B> member;
};
```

I'd like to be able to say:

```
make_T_of_B<X<int>, double> dummy;
```

where X<int> is taken as a single parameter template. It would be equivalent to this template:

```
template<typename B>
struct Y {
    int a;
    B b;
};
```

which looks like how one would specialize X<int, B> without actually changing anything. It's in a way similar to a default specialization -- except that a default specialization doesn't produce another template but rather an actual type (in other words, it's always total).

I realize that I can cascade the template arguments

```
template<typename A>
struct Z1 {
    // start from scratch
    template<typename B>
    struct Z2 {
        A a;
        B b;
    };

    // inherit from double template above
    template<typename B>
    struct X: ::X<A, B> {}; 
};


make_T_of_B<Z1<int>::Z2, double> dummy1;
make_T_of_B<Z1<int>::X, double> dummy2;
```

but I find that to be rather hard to read and not communicate my intentions clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: How about `template <typename T> using Foo = X<int, T>;`? Now you can use `Foo<double>` and get an `X<int, double>`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I was looking for. It's a C++11 feature that I don't have access to, but it answers the question perfectly. I'd like to accept this -- if only it were an answer...

Comment: I added a second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood your question. All you want is a way to bind the first template parameter, which you can do easily like this:

```
template <typename T> using Foo = X<int, T>;
```

Now `Foo<double>` is the same as `X<int, double>`.

Without C++11-style aliases, you can achieve the same with a bit more boilerplate:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    typedef X<int, T> type;
};
```

Now you use `Foo<double>::type`.

Comment: Just a very minor nitpick: the second suggestion, although perfectly acceptable in most cases, can't really work for `make_T_of_B`, there's nothing you can instantiate `make_T_of_B` with to ultimately produce an `X<int, double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a trait:

```
template <typename> struct applicator;

template <template <typename> class Tmpl, typename T>
struct applicator<Tmpl<T>>
{
    template <typename A>
    using rebind = make_T_of_B<Tmpl, A>;
};
```

Now you can say:

```
applicator<X<int>>::rebind<double> dummy;
```

You can of course also move the second argument, `A`, into the main template:

```
template <typename, typename> bpplicator;

template <template <typename> class Tmpl, typename T, typename A>
struct bpplicator<Tmpl<T>, A>
{
    using type = make_T_of_B<Tmpl, A>;  // or "typedef make_T_of_B<Tmpl, A> type;"
};

bpplicator<X<int>, double>::type dummy;
```

This has the advantage that it works in C++03, too.

Comment: You can also try inheritance: `struct bpplictor<Tmpl<T>, A> : make_t_of_B<Tmpl, A>` so you won't need the `using` alias.

Comment: @0x499602D2: But then you get a different type. With my approach, you literally get the same type as if you had said `make_T_of_B<X, double>`.

Comment: `X` (the way I wrote it) is a two parameter template, so `X<int>` will never be parsed successfully, or at least, it isn't for me. I may not have made myself clear, but what I wanted was to get a one parameter template from a two parameter template by fixing its first parameter.